# Access a terminal to execute Queries from Android

Tags: android, sqlite

How can I query my SQLite database of my application from a terminal?

I need it to debug purposes, and also to check values.

I tried from the Emulator Command Line, I moved to the /data/data//databases folder and executed "sqlite3" from there, but .database command doesn't returns my databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a special tool in your sdk folder `tools`. It is called `sqlite3`. Read more [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#sqlite).

THere you'll find all the necessary information like:

> From an adb remote shell, you can use
>   the sqlite3 command-line program to
>   manage SQLite databases created by
>   Android applications. The sqlite3 tool
>   includes many useful commands, such as
>   .dump to print out the contents of a
>   table and .schema to print the SQL
>   CREATE statement for an existing
>   table. The tool also gives you the
>   ability to execute SQLite commands on
>   the fly

Comment: I'm trying to get it, and I still doesn't found how access the database. I also tried from the Emulator Command Line, I moved to the /data/data/<myapk>/databases folder and executed sqlite3 from there and I cant find my db with the .database command.

Comment: I did it by getting the .db file and loading with an external SQLite terminal client. But thank you.